# in VsCode compeltion extention, how should I do to get the index when I accept a completion item?

Tags: visual-studio-code

edit:

[image: like the picture shows]
like the picture shows, I want to get the index of fouced item in the suggestion panel, here is 3.
But I can't get this info from my custom `CompletionItem.command` arguments.

If I got this, I could easily  figure out the Top-N whitch the user prefer to aceept my code suggestion

---

I could tranfer the index of suggestions to it, but it is not correct When there are many suggestions. I mean the index you got is not the exeact index you see in the code completion widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. VS Code controls presentation of the completion items (including sort order) and doesn't expose this back to extensions

If you want to take some action based on which suggestion a user accepts, look at the suggestion that was accepted instead of trying to find its index. As you noted, you can have a command registered on each suggestion that provides feedback when it is accepted

Comment: Year, I can do this. But I just want to get the suggestion order which the user prefer to accept it. I submit a feature request [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/110476),  I'm glad for that if you can vote it.